# My ImageMapType implementation stucks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a basic image map of my own. But I got error with my code. It runs into error on the line I highlighted (with ****). The map fallbacks to default roadmap. The error message is just "Error" and I have no clue what is going on.

Can you please help look into it?

Many thanks!

My javascript code:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-api-key&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script>

      // custom map type
      var mapTypeOptions = {
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
           return 'http://http://placehold.it/256x256.gif';
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        name: 'Some Place',
      };
      var customMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(mapTypeOptions);

      // initalize function
      function initialize() {

        // try to create a new map with custom map type
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.33173, 114.16061),
          zoom: 17,
          minZoom: 17,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.mapTypes.set('ssp', customMapType); // ****
        map.setMapTypeId('ssp');    
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your missing a config setting

```
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: ["ssp"]
}
```

Also, you need to define `maxzoom` for `mapTypeOptions`.

See the example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes

You've also got some validation errors, remove trailing commas before closing an object.